# style for required text field (react-native-material-textfield)

Tags: react-native

How can I set a custom style, so the user can see, that field is required. 
I think of a red star or the label text is not gray but red.
How can I make this?

Thank you für your support.
Rene

Answer (score 2):

please use it as below.

`<TextField label={<><Text>Hello</Text> <Text style={{color:'red'}}>*</Text> </>}/>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to separately style the label or text field you can use Properties provided by react-native-material-textfield. I would suggest you to use following properties and implement whichever looks cool on your UI.

```
label- put label to textfeild

title- put required as a title to textfeild

prefix- prefix your textfeild with required label

suffix- suffix your textfeild with required label

error- provide error proper error message when empty or as per you requirement 

errorColor- here you can put a red color to show that its a required feild

characterRestriction put character restrictions

labelTextStyle style the label

titleTextStyle style the title
```

Or you can use Methods

```
focus()     Acquire focus 

blur()  Release focus

clear()     Clear text field

value()     Get current value   

isFocused()     Get current focus state     

isRestricted()  Get current restriction state
```

As you have not provided your code i have given you basic steps to cuztomize your text field.
Hope this helps, You're good to go!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know this description. labelTextStyle dosn't works. My font color is allways gray...Another style I have not set - only 
labelTextStyle={styles.required}
...
required : {
        color : colors.required ,
    } ,
...
required : 'rgb(218, 41, 28)'